Rewrite 3-loops in simpler integrals
I am working with the following integral, similar to the "setting sun'' diagram by Pierre Ramond in his QFT book:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^dp}{(2 \pi)^d} \int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d} \int \frac{d^d\ell}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{q^2 + q \cdot p +m^2}{\left(\ell^2-m^2\right)\left(q^2-m^2\right)\left([q+p-\ell]^2-m^2\right)}
\end{equation}
Is there a way to rewrite or at least simplify this integral as much as possible in terms of the following predefined integrals:
\begin{equation}
I_1= \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{\Delta_k}, \quad I_2= \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{\Delta_k^2}, \quad I_3= \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{k}{\Delta_k}, \quad I_4= \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{k}{\Delta_k^2}, \quad I_5 = \int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{k_0^2}{\Delta_k^2}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta_k =k^2 - m^2$, $k$ is just to represent the set of momenta $k= \{p,q,\ell\}$.

There should be only 2 momentum integrals if it is a 2-loop diagram

@Mateo you're correct; this is because I am considering the effective potential associated with a 2-loop self-energy. But I will correct the post.

Why don't you use the Feynman parametrization?

There are multiple ways to reduce a 3-loop integral. There is the pure numerical way using a program such as FIRE6. You can also reduce the integral into Passarino-Veltmann coeffiecients using FeynCalc and then evaluate them using Package-X. But, I believe the way you have presented it, and may want it, is via a particular parameterization, but that still won't solve it. You'll need one of the programs above, or use the generalized unitary method for cutting loops and putting them on-shell.
One way to write the integral above, where I have identified the loop configuration as the triple box with external momenta $p_1,...p_4$ with respect to the following Feynman diagram

with the following representation
\begin{equation}
A_{\text{triple box}} = \int\frac{d^dk_1}{(2\pi)^d}\int\frac{d^dk_2}{(2\pi)^d}\int\frac{d^dk_3}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{\Delta_{\text{triple box}}}{\Pi_{i=1}^{10}l_i^2}
\end{equation}
where $l_i = k_1$, $l_2 = k_1-p_1$, $l_3 = k_1-p_1-p_2$, $l_4 = k_3+p_1+p_2$, $l_5 = k_2+p_1+p_2$, $l_6 = k_2 - p_4$, $l_7 = k_2$, $l_8 = k_3$, $l_9 = k_1 + k_3$, and $l_10 = k_2-k_3$.
The $\Delta_{\text{triple box}}$ has a topology that can be written as monomials,
\begin{equation}
\Delta_{\text{triple box}} = \sum_{i_1...i_7}c_{i_1\cdots i_7}(k_1\cdot p_4)^{i_1}\cdots (k_3\cdot \omega)^{i_7}
\end{equation}
where any $\omega$ is defined as $\omega^\mu_\pm = \frac{1}{2}\langle|\sigma^\mu|2] \pm \frac{1}{2}\langle 2|\sigma^\mu|1]$.
Note that this is for the most general 3-loop box integral. The computation simplifies if the on-shell external momenta are all the same. For reference, the notes by Weinzierl (which is now a book) Feynman integrals, and I recommend taking a look at chapter 6. If you want I can attempt the 3-loop integral in Feyncalc and give you the Passarino-Veltmann decomposition.

I suspected that numerical software might be necessary. I've tried working with FeynCalc, but I'm not very proficient with it. If you're familiar with FeynCalc, could you please share the code in your response? It would be incredibly helpful, and I'd greatly appreciate your assistance!
